Google account logout error in web application
I have an application in which you log in with a Google account to see the calendar with the events of that account, my problem comes when it comes to logging out, the code below is the function in charge of logging out:
<!-- Google API -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>

<script>

<!-- rest of code loadConfig()-->

async function handleLogoutClick() {
            console.log('Signing out of Google...');
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Signing out of Google...',
                allowOutsideClick: false,
                didOpen: () => {
                    Swal.showLoading();
                },
            });

            try {
                const token = localStorage.getItem('googleAccessToken');
                if (token) {
                    // Revoke access token
                    await fetch(`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${token}`, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        }
                    });
                    console.log('Token revocado correctamente');
                }

                localStorage.removeItem('googleAccessToken');
                localStorage.setItem('logoutCompletedG', 'true');
                console.log('Google session closed correctly');

                // Disable auto selection if necessary
                if (window.google && window.google.accounts && window.google.accounts.id) {
                    window.google.accounts.id.disableAutoSelect();
                } else {
                    console.error('Google Identity Services is not available.');
                }

                Swal.close();
                window.location.href = 'local.html'; // Redirect to local page after logout

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error revoking token:', error);
                Swal.close();
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Logout error',
                    text: 'An error occurred while trying to log out. Please try again later.'
                });
                console.error('Error signing out of Google', error);
            }
        }


<!-- rest of code initializeGapiClient(), fetchEvents(), renderCalendar(events)-->

I am testing the application with two user accounts. When I log out of one account, the other account should remain logged in. However, when trying to log out of an account, the session is not closed correctly and both accounts are still logged in. This is the message that the console returns to me:
Signing out of Google...

Token revoked successfully

Google session closed correctly

Get failed to load: POST "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}.
handleLogoutClick @VM162 google.html:26
click @ VM162 google.html:173
p @VM160 index.global.min.js:6
S @ VM160 index.global.min.js:6

It is my first development with Google API, thank you very much for the help!
EDIT: I have tried the solution to the question "How to revoke access token of google drive login using google oauth2?" changing the url https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/revoke to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke and nothing, I still have the error when closing the session, the only thing different is that now the error is 400 (Bad Request)

I believe this question is similar to How to revoke access token of google drive login using google oauth2?. Instead of using https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=${token} as your revoke endpoint, try https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke and check if it works.

@Saddles I'm going to read the question you provided me, but trying to change the url to that of googleapi now gives me this error: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke 400 (Bad Request)
